# Jersey response's reason phrase is inconsistent in tomcat 7 and 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, tomcat8.5, httpresponsemessage

I'm using Tomcat 8.5 in one server and Tomcat 7 in different server and I have the following jersey resource:

```
@Path("main")
public class MyResource {


@POST
@Path("path")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public PojoResponse sendMailTemplate(PojoRequest paramsMap) throws Exception {
    return service.execute(paramsMap);
}
```

Which is register to `MyApplication` (`extends ResourceConfig`) with `@ApplicationPath("root")`

When submitting request using JMeter/Postman (to /root/main/path) I'm getting inconsistent HTTP's [Reason Phrase](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)

> The client is not required to examine or display the Reason- Phrase.

Which isn't mandatory for protocol

> The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol.

I see a "valid" response of 200 OK from Tomcat 7 server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 32
```

and an "invalid" response of 200 200 from Tomcat 7 server (same request) :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 200
Server: Apache
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 32
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
```

When I check [Response](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) I don't find any reference to updating reason phrase,
So should this inconsistency be ignored or can it be fixed?

**EDIT**

My application also register JacksonFeature:

```
register(JacksonFeature.class);
```

**EDIT 2**

Actually I found that I have extra jar in second environment:

```
 jersey-entity-filtering-2.19
```

Common jars:

```
jersey-client-2.19.jar
jersey-common-2.19.jar
jersey-container-servlet-2.19.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core-2.19.jar
jersey-guava-2.19.jar
jersey-media-jaxb-2.19.jar
jersey-media-json-jackson-2.6.jar
jersey-server-2.19.jar
jersey-spring3-2.6.jar
```

**EDIT 3**

I found a [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60362) in Tomcat 8.5 which saying reason phrase **was removed**

> Christopher Schultz : I was surprised to see that Tomcat actively strips-out the reason phrase. I had initially thought this was simply Tomcat removing reason-phrases from every response generated by Tomcat (e.g. everything coming from the DefaultServlet, various internal errors, etc.), but it's actively stripping reason phrases explicitly-set by applications.
>
> Michael Osipov:
> No, this does not send any reason phrase. Only the HTML error page. I know, because I have rewritten the ErrorReportValve the last time.

**EDIT 4**

I found [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152778/duplicated-status-code-in-response) but I didn't fully understand it

> Tomcat 8.5 removed the "HTTP status reason phrase" from the response, so you'll get HTTP 200 instead of HTTP 200 OK in the response. It's possible that your observations are from software that duplicates the status code into the status reason phrase for display.
>
> How are you observing the status code? You may find that if you do a protocol trace, you'll see that there is only a single status code being sent by Tomcat / httpd.
> Are you sure the "double status code" isn't actually a (normal) status code and a reason phrase that happens to be the same text as the status code?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha My question is *why is reason phrase different in different servers*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52840360/4116988) (52821653) two days ago.

In short: the current version of HTTP protocol (HTTP/2) has removed support for the reason phrase.

This feature is gone. Do not rely on it.

**UPDATE**:

Looking at

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

and

```
HTTP/1.1 200 200
Server: Apache
```

The HTTP connector of current versions of Tomcat 8.5 by default will respond with `HTTP/1.1 200` (with no reason phrase). See `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer`.

The AJP connector of current versions of Tomcat 8.5 by default will respond with `HTTP/1.1 200 200` (using the status code as the reason phrase), because of limitations of some HTTP servers. See `org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor`.

Both responses are valid ones.

Generating the "OK" string can be enabled in Tomcat 8.5 by setting `sendReasonPhrase="true"` on a [Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html). This option is deprecated.

Comment: In the question it's about seeing *standard Not Authorized message* and not the status code

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the cause is the same: this feature has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you are looking for may be found in [RFC 2616, section 6](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html).

The relevant excerpt:

> The Status-Code is intended for use by automata and the Reason-Phrase is intended for the human user. The client is not required to examine or display the Reason- Phrase.

The main take-away is that the reason-phrase should not be relied on in your client code. However, you can and should rely on the Status-Code.

If you wish to convey additional human readable context in your HTTP responses, it is common practice, to place this in a 'custom' response header (e.g. "X-MyApp-Message"). Note that custom headers should begin with 'X-'.

Comment: My question is *why is reason phrase different in different servers*

Comment: Have you identified the Jersey implementation versions on each of the servers in question? Are they the same or different? If they are different, then you can chalk that up to arbitrary code changes.  These differences don't violate the protocol as defined in the RFC, and it's a mistake to rely on them.

Comment: Similar Jersey implementations results in same response

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using Apache Server 2.4.6 which has a bug, One of Changes of Apache 2.4.7 is fixing [reason phrase to be returned](https://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.4):

> core: Add missing Reason-Phrase in HTTP response headers.
>        PR 54946. [Rainer Jung]

The [relevant bug](https://grokbase.com/t/apache/bugs/1359myw1pz/bug-54946-new-missing-reason-phrase-in-http-response-header-for-standard-3-digit-status-codes) states it's a breaking change:

> we would get
>   a http status-line pulled from a standard table like:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1<sp>200<sp>OK
> ```
>
> Now, in Apache 2.2.24 we are getting:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1<sp>200<sp>
> ```
>
> We tracked this down into a change made for apache bug 44995 that caused this
>   new behavior. The bug was a fix to handle custom status codes, but it also
>   ended up breaking standard codes such that it no longer returned standard
>   reason-phrase enhanced responses.
>
> I realize that the RFC2616 specification allows for the HTTP/1.1200
>   response, but our client is not changeable and crashes on receiving no
>   reason-phrase.