# Custom HTTP reason phrase using ExceptionMapper

Tags: tomcat, jax-rs, http-status-codes, exceptionmapper

I have defined the following Exception Mapper to handle the custom `HttpCustomException`

```
package com.myapp.apis;

import com.myapp.apis.model.HttpCustomException;
import com.myapp.apis.model.HttpCustomExceptionStatusType;
import com.myapp.apis.model.HttpCustomNotAuthorizedException;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class HttpCustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper <HttpCustomException> {

  @Override
  public Response toResponse (HttpCustomException e) {
    Response response = Response.status (new HttpCustomExceptionStatusType (Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage ())).build ();
    if (e instanceof HttpCustomNotAuthorizedException) {
      response = Response.status (new HttpCustomExceptionStatusType (Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage ())).build ();
    }

    System.out.println ("HttpCustomExceptionMapper: " + response.getStatus () + ", " + response.getStatusInfo ().getReasonPhrase ());
    return response;
  }
}
```

When a `HttpCustomNotAuthorizedException` is thrown in the code, I can see the log message defined in the end of the `toResponse` method, in catalina.out. So, the HttpCustomExceptionMapper class is being invoked during the request processing. But, in the final response, I see in the client, I only see the standard `Not Authorized` message and not the custom message I set in the Response.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Perhaps because you are propagating the standard `e.getMessage ()`. Try adding a custom string to that to test.

Comment: I had set a custom string when I threw the exception in the code. I can confirm that `e.getMessage()` gives a custom string based on the print statement in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should note that the current version of HTTP protocol (HTTP/2) does not support a reason phrase at all. It has been removed from the protocol.

Thus support for sending a reason phrase has been removed from Tomcat 9.0 onwards. In Tomcat 7.0, 8.5 support for sending a custom reason phrase is off by default (can be enabled with a [system property](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html#Other), `org.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER`). In 8.5 you also should set `sendReasonPhrase="true"` on a [Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot of this. This was exactly the issue!

Answer (score 1):

It is showing the the standard response because you are not setting the body for your response you are only setting the status. 
You have to passe the custom response like this :

```
Response response = Response.status (Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(CustomResponse).build ();
```

am not okay with the design, but it will be something like :

```
HttpCustomExceptionStatusType  status = new HttpCustomExceptionStatusType (Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage ())
Response response = Response.status (status).entity(status).build ();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the response body can also be configured :)